# Convert a list of delimited strings to a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, split

I am importing arrays from a CSV file.

Example:

```
arr = ['foo1;foo2;foo3', 'baa1;baa2;baa3', 'bla1;bla2;bla3']
```

I now want to transform these semicolon seperated strings to a list of lists:

```
arr2 = [['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'], ['baa1', 'baa2', 'baa3'], ['bla1', 'bla2', 'bla3']]
```

---

How can I do this? I am struggling to find the right combination of `split`, `append` and delimiters to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
arr2 = [s.split(';') for s in arr]
```